# Query Parameters passing into function for onFormSubmit trigger

Tags: html, forms, google-apps-script, triggers, query-string

Is there a way to take query parameters from a Google Apps Script Web App onFormSubmit? I know it can be done using a doGet(e) but that's at the start of a form when it's opened. I want to take the query parameters when the user submits the form

For example in the following link, I want to be able to take the ID onFormSubmit and send it to a webhook URL.

https://script.google.com/a/domain.com/macros/s/Adlksjflf09_LEg8kdlf9/exec?ID=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Direct to a new page after form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52279423/direct-to-a-new-page-after-form-submission)

Comment: @Rubén i don't believe this a duplicate. The first answer is doing a windows.location to a static url without getting the query parameters from the initial url

Comment: Even the answer includes windows.location it's showing how to use an URL query parameter on a Google Apps Script web app.

Comment: All functions that are associated with an event receive an event object.  There is a "Form Submit" event for both Forms and Sheets, but the event object for each is different.  See the [documentation for event objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)  Unfortunately, the Sheets Form Submit event object does not include the response ID of the submitted response. Are you are using the Sheets Form Submit trigger?  You could do what you want to do with a Forms Form Submit trigger.